# DjangoCMS - how do i match my html projects templates to DjangoCMS pages?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-cms

i'm trying to integrate djangoCMS to my django website but after selecting a page on the DjangoCMS templates down, the rendered page does not show the placeholders in the structure view, it just displays an empty sidebar, can someone help me please?

Comment: which django CMS version are you using?

Comment: i know this is a bit late but im using djangoCMS 3.5